# How to convey multiple variables through single emit() in OMNET++?

Tags: omnet++

According to OMNET++ Simulation Manual the types can be carried by emit() are, "*The value can be of type bool, long, double, simtime_t, const char * , or (const) cObject * . Other types can be cast into one of these types, or wrapped into an object subclassed from cObject.*"

So to pass multiple vairables through single emit(), cObject must be used. The Manual's solution for this is to create a class driven from cObject to hold the values and pass it to the emit().

```
 class cRawTableData : public cObject, noncopyable
{
public:
    unsigned int sVehicleID;
    double sPositionX;                    
    double sPositionY;                                     
    double sSpeed;                    
};

if (hasListeners(rawTableSignal)){
cRawTableData tmp;
tmp.sVehicleID=senderId;
tmp.sPositionX=senderPOx;
tmp.sPositionY=senderPOy;
tmp.sSpeed=senderSpeed;
emit(rawTableSignal, &tmp);
}
```

However, when I run the simulation I get this error:

```
omnetpp::VectorRecorder: Cannot convert cObject* to double
```

[image: run-time error]

What is that I am doing wrong? thank you for the help

Comment: Have you tried to convey Map or Vector instead?